# Bad linking in Qt unit test -- missing the link to the moc file?

Tags: unit-testing, qt

I'm trying to unit test a class that inherits QObject; the class itself is located up one level in my directory structure. When I build the unit test I get the standard unresolved errors if a class' MOC file cannot be found:

```
test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __thiscall UnitToTest::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@UnitToTest@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)

+ 2 missing functions
```

The MOC file is created but appears to not be linking.  I've been poking around SO, the web, and Qt's docs for quite a while and have hit a wall.

**How do I get the unit test to include the MOC file in the link?**

====

My project file is dead simple:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = test
DESTDIR = .
CONFIG += qtestlib
INCLUDEPATH += . ..
DEPENDPATH += .
HEADERS += test.h
SOURCES += test.cpp ../UnitToTest.cpp stubs.cpp
DEFINES += UNIT_TEST
```

My directory structure and files:

```
C:.
| UnitToTest.cpp
| UnitToTest.h
|
\---test
    |   test.cpp       (Makefiles removed for clarity)
    |   test.h
    |   test.pro
    |   stubs.cpp
    |
    +---debug
    |       UnitToTest.obj
    |       test.obj
    |       test.pdb
    |       moc_test.cpp
    |       moc_test.obj
    |       stubs.obj
```

**Edit:** Additional information

The generated `Makefile.Debug` shows the moc file missing:

```
SOURCES       = test.cpp \
        ..\test.cpp \
        stubs.cpp debug\moc_test.cpp
OBJECTS       = debug\test.obj \
        debug\UnitToTest.obj \
        debug\stubs.obj \
        debug\moc_test.obj
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add ../UnitToTest.h to HEADERS in the pro file.

Comment: Wow.  Annoyingly simple; just as I thought it would be.

Comment: That might have saved me a lot of frustration. Thanks!